# Xamarin Forms: scroll position in scrollview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, scrollview

Is there no possibility to read and set the position of the scrollview? For example, I would like to start the app with the scroll position at the bottom, not at the top.

Comment: Nothing. But i can't find any properties or methods which look like they do something like this.

Comment: For Android, I have found a solution: I write a custom renderer and in the OnDraw override Method, I call FullScroll(FocusSearchDirection.Down) the first time when the method is called.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the X and Y position of a ScrollView from the ScrollX and ScrollY properties of the ScrollView object. Then you can set the position with the ScrollView method ScrollToAsync.

```
var x = scrollView.ScrollX;
var y = scrollView.ScrollY;

...

bool animate = false;
scrollView.ScrollToAsync(x, y, animate);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've a better approach to this!

You can add this to your onAppearing() method:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        /*Other stuff*/

        viewModel.Messages.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var target = viewModel.Messages[viewModel.Messages.Count - 1];                

            ItemsListView.ScrollTo(target, ScrollToPosition.End, false);
        };            
    }
```

This means that if your collection change, you get the target which is the last item (the one in the bottom) the you use scrollTo target, position end, with animation false.

when you get to the page it will open in the bottom, you don't see the scrolling because animation is false!

Answer (score 0):

For Android, I have found a solution:

I write a custom renderer and in the `OnDraw` override Method, I call `FullScroll(FocusSearchDirection.Down)` the first time when the method is called.

What it makes easy, the Android `ScrollViewRenderer` is subtype of `Android.Widget.ScrollView`.

At the moment, I don't need an implementation for iOS, so I have no solution for iOS.